# ActionScript 3.0 TypeError #1009 Null object? but there is no null object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, typeerror

I am making a game in flash and my only problem so far is this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at farmgame227_fla::MainTimeline/onenter()[farmgame227_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:144]
```

The line will vary depending on how I move to the next frame. I am 99% sure a null object is not the problem, so I am stumped. I will show my entire code for frame 2 and I would appreciate it so much if anyone could lend some insight.

```
stop();

import flash.events.Event;


addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);

stop();

//starting positions for sheep
sheep1.y = 330
sheep1.x = 350

sheep2.y = 360
sheep2.x = 380

sheep3.y = 300
sheep3.x = 450

sheep4.y = 330
sheep4.x = 350

gold.y = 150
gold.x = 800

goat.y = 620
goat.x = 800

var myscore = 0;


function onenter(e:Event)
{

    //hand follows mouse cursor
    hand.x = mouseX;
    hand.y = mouseY;

    //sheep velocity
    sheep1.x = sheep1.x + 1;
    sheep1.y = sheep1.y - 1;

    sheep2.x = sheep2.x - 1;
    sheep2.y = sheep2.y - 1;

    sheep3.x = sheep3.x + 1;
    sheep3.y = sheep3.y + 1;

    sheep4.x = sheep4.x - 3;
    sheep4.y = sheep4.y + 3;

    //sheep1's boundaries
    if (sheep1.y < 0 || sheep1.y > 775 || sheep1.x < 0 || sheep1.x > 775)
    {       
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);
        nextFrame();
    }

    //sheep2's boundaries
    if (sheep2.y < 0 || sheep2.y > 775 || sheep2.x < 0 || sheep2.x > 775)
    {       
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);
        nextFrame();
    }

    //sheep3's boundaries
    if (sheep3.y < 0 || sheep3.y > 775 || sheep3.x < 0 || sheep3.x > 775)
    {       
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);
        nextFrame();
    }

    //sheep4's boundaries
    if(sheep4==null)
    {
        trace("4 it's null");
    }
    if (sheep4.y < 0 || sheep4.y > 775 || sheep4.x < 0 || sheep4.x > 775)
    {       
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);
        nextFrame();
    }

    //hand hitting sheep, sending them back
    if(sheep1==null)
    {
        trace("1 is null");
    }
    if(hand==null)
    {
        trace("hand is null");
    }
    if(fence==null)
    {
        trace("fence is null");
    }
    if (hand.hitTestObject (sheep1))
    {
        sheep1.y = 330;
        sheep1.x = 350;
        myscore = myscore + 1;
    }
    if (hand.hitTestObject (sheep2))
    {
        sheep2.y = 360;
        sheep2.x = 380;
        myscore = myscore + 1;
    }
    if (hand.hitTestObject (sheep3))
    {
        sheep3.y = 300;
        sheep3.x = 450;
        myscore = myscore + 1;
    }
    if (hand.hitTestObject (sheep4))
    {
        sheep4.y = 330;
        sheep4.x = 350;
        myscore = myscore + 1;
    }

    if (hand.hitTestObject (gold))
    {
        gold.x = 2500;
        gold.y = 610;
        gold.x = gold.x - 9;
        myscore = myscore + 5;
    }

    if (hand.hitTestObject (goat))
    {       
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);
        nextFrame();
    }


    //hand touching fence, results in game over
    if (hand.hitTestObject (fence))
    {       
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);
        nextFrame();
    }

    score.text = myscore;

    //changing sheep speed based on score
    //score 40 and 55 should be next
    if (myscore >= 12)
    {
        sheep2.x = sheep2.x - 2;
        sheep2.y = sheep2.y - 2;
    }

    if (myscore >= 24)
    {
        sheep3.x = sheep3.x + 2;
        sheep3.y = sheep3.y + 2;
    }

    if (myscore >= 30)
    {
        sheep1.x = sheep1.x + 3;
        sheep1.y = sheep1.y - 3;
    }

    //initiating and controlling gold and goat
    if (myscore > 17)
    {
        gold.x = gold.x - 8;
    }

    if (gold.x < -9)
    {
        gold.x = 2000;
        gold.y = 610;
        gold.x = gold.x - 9;
    }

    if (myscore > 8)
    {
        goat.x = goat.x - 3;
    }

    if (goat.x < -9)
    {
        goat.x = 1600;
        goat.y = 150;
        goat.x = goat.x - 4;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should shift all the checks in `onenter` upwards, prior to assigning anything to either sheep or other objects. Then you will likely find that one of the objects is null. The #1009 error means that some object reference that's placed right before a "." qualifier is null, and you can't get properties out of nothing.

Also, try placing `return` right after any call of `nextFrame()`, because when you perform nextframe, the previous frame's vars are invalidated, thus you can't refer to say `hand` because there's no more hand, it's destroyed along with the whole previous frame.

Comment: adding `return;` after each `nextFrame();` fixed the error! You were spot on! I can't thank you enough, this made my day.